# file_get_contents in PHP not working

Tags: php, screen, file-get-contents, scrape

For a class project, we are supposed to pull data from another website. I picked pulling games similar to a given game from GiantBomb.com (credits are given to them on my script)

```
// $gameLink = "/call-of-duty-black-ops/61-26423/";
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.giantbomb.com" . urlencode($gameLink) . "games_similar/");
echo $html;
```

This returns nothing.

However, if $gameLink is manually typed:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.giantbomb.com/call-of-duty-black-ops/61-26423/games_similar/");
echo $html;
```

Now, it will properly return a result. What's wrong with my code? I tried performing `urlencode()` on the entire link and not just the $gameLink variable but it still fails. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: ... That's not what `urlencode()` is for...

Comment: @Sunny, be sure to tag questions related to class as `homework`.

Comment: Also, be sure to accept the answer that answers your question by clicking the checkbox below the voting arrows. See [How do I ask a question here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) in the FAQ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are only required to urlencode links embedded in html. Don't urlencode links passed to file_get_contents().

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is because urlencode() encodes all non-alphanumeric characters except for -_.

This means that your forward slashes get encoded into %2F, which is not what you want ;) However, as hegemon has mentioned above, don't urlencode links passed to file_get_contents().